# How to reverse video by default in Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24

I am running Emacs 24.3.1 on Mac OS 10.9, compiled on my machine from source through MacPorts. (For good measure I also tried a 24.3 binary from emacsformacosx.com.) I can use the `-r` switch from the command line to get Emacs to run in reverse video, however adding a customization to my .emacs file `(setq inverse-video t)` or through the Emacs customization menu is having no effect. Does anyone know another way to reverse the video without running Emacs from the command line?

Comment: Use aquamacs and configure its preferences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the usual [Emacs init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)
(`~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) is read *after* the GUI is initialized, so it has *no* effect on reverse video. You have to stick with the command line option [`--reverse-video` or `-rv` or `-r`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Colors-X.html).

However, Emacs 28.1 (not yet released) adds an *early* init file `‘~/.emacs.d/early-init.el` which is loaded *before* GUI is initialized, and if you put

```lisp
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(reverse . t))
(setq initial-frame-alist default-frame-alist)
```

into it, your Emacs will start with reverse video.

Comment: Yes, that is what the Emacs customization menu adds to .emacs. It doesn't seem to do anything. What you wrote above is the entire (non-comment) contents of my .emacs.

Comment: Actually, that's pretty much the same as `(setq inverse-video t)`.

Comment: I have just tested this on emacs on MacOS as per the original request and this does not work for me at all.

Comment: with emacs 25.3 on macOS 10.14.6 that still just leaves the default black on white for me.

Comment: The solution presented worked for GNU Emacs 27.1, seven years after asking the question. This is part of the reason I use VimR now.

Comment: Works for me in 29.1.

Answer (score 4):

I put this in my .emacs file: (Running GNU Emacs 21.1.3 on x86 linux)

```
(set-background-color "black")
(set-foreground-color "white")
```

Edit / update:
Works just fine for the first frame. But a new frame is opened with a white background, and black text.  Have some vague recollection of separately setting the frame background/foreground colors in the past, but don't know the name of the setting.

Comment: Thanks, the black is too much though...  `(set-background-color "grey25")`

Answer (score 2):

I have found this solution which "works for me" on GNU emacs 25.3.1 running on macOS High Sierra / 10.13.2.  It's obviously a bit of a hack but maybe it's a good start towards a more solid solution.

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
   (progn (setq default-frame-alist
             (cons (cons 'reverse t) default-frame-alist))
     (select-frame (make-frame))
     (delete-other-frames) )
 )
```

the if clause means that the normal terminal based emacs doesn't get messed up by this.

Answer (score 0):

Run emacs with the ReverseVideo flag in Linux:

```
$ emacs -rv &
```

Comment: this will also work on mac but you need to use the direct path.  Something like

    ```/Applications/Emacs/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -rv```

for example.

Comment: But that was what the original poster wanted to replace. -r = -rv.

Answer (score 0):

This works in 25.1 (and 27.2) on Linux, Windows, and MacOS:

```
(set-face-background  'default   "black")
(set-face-foreground  'default   "white")
```

New frames are handled too.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Emacs 24.3 downloaded from emacsformacosx.com on Mac 10.8.5.

Launch the AppleScript Editor, paste in the below line.

```
do shell script "open -a Emacs.app --args -r"
```

Now save as "ReverseEmacs" (or your preferred application name) with a File Format of "Application."  Double-click your script icon and up comes Emacs with reverse video. Enjoy!